# Avoid multiple if-else conditions for different enum values in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

I have 6 values in the enum and using 6 if-else is really a bad practice.
Can we implement this in any better way? Below is my scenario :

```
ExampleEnum value = getEnumValue();

if(ExampleEnum.A == value){
   doA();
}else if(ExampleEnum.B == value){
   doB();
}else if(ExampleEnum.C == value){
   doC();
}else if(ExampleEnum.D == value){
   doD();
}else if(ExampleEnum.E == value){
   doE();
}else if(ExampleEnum.F == value){
   doF();
}
```

I was thinking of switch, but is is not making much difference also i need to return a boolean value inside doA() depending on certain parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a `switch`? It makes a difference concerning readability...

Comment: Use a switch expression or/and try to extract common functionality from `doA`-`doF` to combine cases in the switch expression (if possible). Besides that, there is not much to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

#### A chain of `else-if`s

Leave your code as-is. Hard to read and write.

#### Switch

```
switch (value) {
    case A:
        doA();
        break;
    case B:
        doB();
        break;
    case C:
        doC();
        break;
    case D:
        doD();
        break;
    case E:
        doE();
        break;
    case F:
        doF();
        break;
}
```

Note that this is the classic switch. If you have access to newer Java versions, it is probably possible to get rid of the `break`s.

#### `EnumMap`

You can also create an `EnumMap`:

```
EnumMap<ExampleEnum, Runnable> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(Map.<ExampleEnum, Runnable>of(
    ExampleEnum.A, Main::doA, // 'Main', or wherever your do* methods are.
    ExampleEnum.B, Main::doB,
    ExampleEnum.C, Main::doC, // I'm using method references. But you could
    ExampleEnum.D, Main::doD, // also use lambda expressions: '() -> doD()'.
    ExampleEnum.E, Main::doE,
    ExampleEnum.F, Main::doF
));

ExampleEnum value = getEnumValue();
enumMap.get(value).run();
```

Comment: I tought _a few options_ is plural and not singular.

Comment: Correct. I was still listing the other ones.

Comment: Havent tought of `Map`, really good point. You should add something like an `Handler` interface and register one for each enum type. This is also clear in terms of SOC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `switch` statement and you're on Java 12 or newer, consider using [extended switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) that avoid the pitfalls of `break` statements:

```java
switch (value) {
    case A -> doA();
    case B -> doB();
    case C -> doC();
    case D -> doD();
    case E -> doE();
    case F -> doF();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the do method inside the enum.

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    A {
        public void doIt() { ... }
    },
    B {
        public void doIt() { ... }
    },
    ...

    abstract public void doIt();

}

ExampleEnum value = getEnumValue();
if (value != null) {
    value.doIt();
}
```

Comment: Don't use keywords as variable or method names, it won't simply compile.

Comment: Thanks, it was more pseudo-code than actual code but indeed I can't use do as method name. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i cannot edit this Enum its being used at other places as well. I tried to create a new enum with abstract methods in it say for eg. MapExampleEnum with same values  as the original one. But not able to cast value to MapExampleEnum